# SQL Server stored procedure display message after insert

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm pretty new to stored procedures.

I'm using SQL Server.

I'm trying to execute a stored procedure so that after the `INSERT` it returns a message 'Insert complete' or if it didn't insert 'Insert failed'

I'm receiving an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@oResult"

I can't figure it out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
ALTER PROC master
    @iPatientFName varchar(20),
    @iPatientLName varchar(20),
    @iPatientAddr varchar(30),
    @iDOB date,
    @oResult VARCHAR(10) OUT    
AS

DECLARE @wardCount int
SET @wardCount = (SELECT COUNT(ward_id) FROM dbo.patient_admissions_tbl)
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if(@wardCount < 5)
        BEGIN           
            INSERT INTO patient_tbl(patient_fname, patient_lname,     patient_address, patient_dob)
            VALUES(@iPatientFName, @iPatientLName, @iPatientAddr, @iDOB)                        
            SET @oResult = 'Patient inserted'
        END         
END


EXECUTE exam_master 'john', 'smith', 'new york', '10-10-1981', @oResult
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @oResult VARCHAR(10);
EXECUTE exam_master 'john', 'smith', 'new york', '10-10-1981', @oResult OUTPUT;

PRINT(@oResult); --if you want to see result value
```